# Domain url formed issue

Tags: joomla-2.5, jroute

I have a problem with how the internal links of a website are formed while using the JRoute class. Instead of them being in the following format:

```
www-mydomain-gr/[the rest of the url]
```

they are formed like this:

```
www-anotherdomain-gr/[the rest of the url]
```

where the ‘anotherdomain-gr’ is another website in the shared server.

We tried to overcome the problem by placing the ‘mydomain-gr’ in the $live_site of the configuration file:

```
$live_site = ‘www-mydomain-gr’
```

The problem is still there though. Why does it do that when I specifically added my domain to $live_site?

Is there another way, except $live_site, to clearly and explicitly force the system to use only the domain ‘www-mydomain-gr’, so it doesn’t have to look for it when it forms the links?

Comment: Have any manual changes been made to the htaccess file?

Comment: Hello Lodder

Thank you very much for your quick reply.

Manual changes no, but changes made by Admin Tools pro extension.
Security related changes and redirects from non-www to www and from index.php to root

Comment: As a clue: Use phpMyAdmin and export your website's database (save output to a file). Then open the file and search for "anotherdomain" or whatever it is. Not found? Use a find-in-file command like `grep -ri "anotherdomain" ./` for Linux or `findstr /s /i /c:"anotherdomain" *.*` for Windows where you are in the root of your website. You may download the whole files and folder in your computer and use these commands. Not found? Try to search the domain without any dot (`.`). Not found? "anotherdomain" might be encrypted. You may consider disabling suspicious plugins/components one by one.